# dreamweaver automatically creating a new folder

Tags: php, dreamweaver

Ok I didn't see this anywhere and Google isn't helping it keeps directing me how to create a folder.

So my issue is this, I have a login page that I'm trying to test. When I hit f12 to show the page in a browser (on my localhost) some how dreamweaver  is creating a new folder within a folder and placing the file I just saved in a completely different folder in there and renaming the file with random characters.

so in effect it is doing this :

file name is login.php, folder location is admin, so my page should show as this in the url

```
    admin/login.php
```

but instead it is showing this

```
    Mysite/Mysite/admin/KOyilwoe.php
```

is is actually creating these folders as well so it is showing in my dreamweaver folder structure as

```
    Mysite/Mysite/Mysite/admin/KOyilwoe.php
```

Of course when it does this it breaks all links to images and any connections I'm trying to make to the database.

I am using Dreamweaver CS4 does anyone know why it would do this? I have tested many sites before on my localhost and never had this issue until this website. Is this possibly a setting in dreamweaver itself or would a javascript be causing it? I did try removing the javascript and it was still creating the new folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I posted a similar question on Adobe's forums and they responded with this and yes it does fix the issue.

Dreamweaver creates a temporary page. It's created specifically for previewing.

You "should" be able to turn it off in the preferences...

Edit > Preferences >select Preview In Browser > uncheck the "Preview using temporary file" checkbox

EDIT: OOps, forgot the Preview In Browser selection.